# Calculating area of habitat suitability map obtained from Maxent using ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, area, maxent, habitat-modeling

I am doing a species distribution modelling using Maxent. I got the species distribution maps from maxent and I reclassified the map into four group as high, moderate, low and unsuitable areas in ArcMap 10.7.1. The projection of the raster is WGS84 with a resolution of 30 arc second.

How can I calculate the areas (in square km) based on the above four groups?

Comment: Use the projection tool to project your dataset from WGS84 into an appropriate coordinate system with units of metres for your region. You'll then be able to compute areas in sensible units. If you had actually said where your data is may be others could have suggested an appropriated projected coordinate system for you to use...

Comment: Okay. Thank you.